# Owlcarousel version 2.3.4 and custom owl carousel addClassActive not working

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have a problem. I am using owl carousel v2.3.4 and i have created a custom  owl dots. Custom dots is working but **addClassActive** not working. here is my example :

```js
var action = false, clicked = false;
    var Owl = {
        init: function() {
          Owl.carousel();
        },
        carousel: function() {
            var owl;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                
                owl = $('.testimonial_slider').owlCarousel({
                    items      : 1,
                    center     : true,
                    autoplay   : true,
                    nav        : false,
                    dots       : true,
                    addClassActive : true,
                    loop       : true,
                    margin     : 10,
                    dotsContainer : '.custom_owl_carousel',
                });

                  $('.owl-next').on('click',function(){
                    action = 'next';
                  });
                  $('.owl-prev').on('click',function(){
                    action = 'prev';
                  });

                $('.custom_owl_carousel').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
                    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
    Owl.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this solution. I have removed this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

line. It's working.